# function for creating combinations of strings

Tags: php, function

I'll do my best to describe what I'm trying to accomplish:

Lets say for every letter I have one or more replacements:

```
a = a
b = X, Z
c = c
d = W, V, M
e = e
```

If I'm given a string, say 'abcd', I want to create strings with combinatons of replacements, so for example 'abcd' would produce following combinations:

```
aXcW
aXcV
aXcM
aZcW
aZcV
aZcM
```

Can you help me write a function that will create and spit out an array of all the combinations regardless of how many replacements are per letter and how many occurances of replacements are in a string? So it should work with ab and abbbdddd.

Thanks

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth nothing at this point, thinking.

Comment: Sounds like universal turing machine stuff (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine).

Comment: Considered looking at array_map()?  You can just write a function that works with only one letter and its replacement set at a time, then hook it up with array_map() which will allow you to run it on, say, an array of all of the characters in the string (which you can get from using str_split() on your string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a simple recursive solution for you

```
function repl($str, $map) {
    if(strlen($str) == 0)
        return array('');
    $out = array();
    foreach(repl(substr($str, 1), $map) as $r)
        foreach($map[$str[0]] as $sub)
            $out[] = $sub . $r;
    return $out;
}
```

use like this

```
$map = array(
    'a' => array('1', '2', '3'),
    'b' => array('@', '*'),
    'c' => array('X', 'Y', 'Z')
);

$result = repl("abc", $map);
```

To work for utf8 strings (or arbitrary substrings), the function should accept array of strings:

```
function repl($chars, $map) {
    if(count($chars) == 0)
        return array('');
    $out = array();
    foreach(repl(array_slice($chars, 1), $map) as $r)
        foreach($map[$chars[0]] as $sub)
            $out[] = $sub . $r;
    return $out;
}
```

use like this

```
preg_match_all('~.~u', $str, $m);
$chars = $m[0];
$result = repl($chars, $map);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. Now I'm trying to make work with $map keys being utf8 characters